# How in Tailwind CSS to use classes with arbitrary values

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm a newbie with Tailwind CSS. By the link https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support I see that we can use classes with arbitrary values like

```
class="bg-[#1da1f1]"
```

But browser doesn't see classes containing the characters `[`, `]`, `#` and so on.

So how to use them or how are they used in Tailwind? I don't get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Characters like `[`,`]`,`#` are escaped in the css selector.
Reference - [CSS classes with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273188/css-classes-with-special-characters)

Like this -

```
.bg-\[\#333\] {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```