# Tailwind CSS Arbitrary Values Doesn't Work With Pug?

Tags: pug, tailwind-css

I have an issue when using Tailwind CSS `v3.0.18` arbitrary values in pug files. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832355/7040296) but it doesn't solve the issue.

Here is my pug file:

```
.container.mx-auto.flex.items-center.space-x-1
  .box.p-8.bg-yellow-800.text-white(class="w-1/2")
    h1.font-bold(class='text-2xl') It's normal
  .box.p-8.bg-yellow-800.text-white(class="w-[50%]")
    h1.font-bold(class='text-\[40px\]') It Doesn't Work
```

So, what is the correct way to apply Tailwind CSS arbitrary values in pug?

Comment: Just as an advice, do not stick to pug. It's nice in the beginning because the template looks slick but you'll soon realize that you will have a lot of those small quirks down the road. Went there, now using regular HTML because I don't want to spend hours on debugging my build tool. Not answer the question per se, sorry for that.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how it does not work? What stack are you using (vue, react .. etc). The code is compiling and working correctly in my test.

Comment: The person who posted the question and the one of the bounty are not the same so yeah, more info would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&attributes`

```
&attributes({ class: 'text-[#ff0]' })
```

Full usage:

```
script(src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com")

.w-16.h-16.bg-red-500&attributes({ class: 'text-[#ff0]' })
  | Text
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use other symbols - in `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  separator: '_',
}
```