# Why is my dynamic bootstrap table not working in PUG Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, pug

So here is a example of section of vue code with a dynamic bootstrap table. This code works where if i click on a depart_time cell the datepicker element is activated.

```
<template>
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template v-for="(field, index) in fields" #[`cell(${field.key})`]="data">
      <b-form-datepicker v-if="field.type === 'date' && items[data.index].isEdit && selectedCell === field.key" :key="index" :type="field.type" :value="items[data.index][field.key]" @input="(value) => inputHandler(value, data.index, field.key)"></b-form-datepicker>
      <span :key="index" v-else @click="editCellHandler(data, field.key)">{{data.value}}</span>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "EditableTable",
  components: {},
  props: {},
 
  data() {
    return {
      selectedCell: null,
      fields: [
        { key: "nr", label: "nr", type: 'text' },
        { key: "depart_time", label: "Depart_time", type: 'date'},
        { key: "edit", label: "", type: "edit" }
      ],
      items: [        
        {"id": 138963919919352, "nr": "6", "depart_time": "2023-09-14 18:50:00"  },       
        {"id": 74566003611616,"nr": "1","depart_time": "2023-09-14 19:20:00"},
        {"id": 160994781676955, "nr": "2", "depart_time": "2023-09-14 20:30:00"},
   
      ].map(item => ({...item, isEdit: false})),
    }
  },
    methods: {
      editCellHandler(data, name) {
         this.items = this.items.map(item => ({...item, isEdit: false}));
         this.items[data.index].isEdit = true;
         this.selectedCell = name
      },
      inputHandler(value, index, key) {
        this.items[index][key] = value;
      }
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

This code gives an output like the following which is what i want but just using pug:
[image]

When i change the html to use PUG, still using exact same datasets, it prints the table but if i click on the depart_time nothing happens. The select and edit functionality stopped working. I thought that this might have to do with syntax issues when translating the html to PUG.

Here is the PUG version of the above html:

```
        template
          b-table(:items='items' :fields='fields')
            template(v-for='(field, index) in fields', #[`cell(${field.key})`]='data')
              b-form-datepicker(v-if="field.type === 'date' && items[data.index].isEdit && selectedCell === field.key" :key='index', :type='field.type' , :value='items[data.index][field.key]', @input='(value) => inputHandler(value, data.index, field.key)')
              span(:key='index' v-else @click='editCellHandler(data, field.key)') {{data.value}}
```

The pug output is just a static table that shows the data but has no editable functionality.
[image]
This was done in   "vue": "^2.6.14"

Can anybody please advise how to make this work in PUG?

I tried converting the html to pug using an online converter but it gives different outputs

Comment: Sharing the comment I posted elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71097792/tailwind-css-arbitrary-values-doesnt-work-with-pug#comment135938349_71097792